# Z3: Expressing Array equivalence

Tags: z3

I'm expressing memory as Z3Arrays. And I want to express that the two arrays are same i.e. their contents are same.

How can I do the same in Z3?

Answer (score 0):

Standard equality should be fine. See also our example programs where this is shown, e.g., in ([.NET](https://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#examples/dotnet/Program.cs) or the [arrays section in the Z3 Guide](http://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorialcontent/guide#h26).